# Bootstrap 3 cols within loop in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop

I'd like to have your opinion concerning this piece of code, which actually works.
I'm building a loop to get 3 cols in rows within a loop with bootstrap2. Here is my code :

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- span4 -->
    <?php 
    $count = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) : ?>
        <!-- end of row when $i values +2cols --> 
        <?php if ($i%3 == 0): $count = $i+2; ?>
            <div class="row">
        <?php endif ?>

                <div class="span4">
                    Col <?php echo $i ?>
                </div>

        <?php if ($count == $i): ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

I instanciated a `$count` to state if this is the last col and get the row closed at this moment. 
I already saw some simplier pieces of code which are said to work, but don't.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I delete the count var and put the right modulo. on the last `if` statement must be equal to the desired number of cols minus 1 (-1) :

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- span4 -->
    <?php 
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) : ?>
        <!-- no more count var --> 
        <?php if ($i%3 == 0): ?>
            <div class="row">
        <?php endif ?>

                <div class="span4">
                    Col <?php echo $i ?>
                </div>
    <!-- here the equality will always be the nbr of cols minus 1, so 2 here --> 
        <?php if ($i%3 == 2): ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I always found it cleaner to wrap everything in `<div class='row'></div>` then close and reopen the tags when you hit the end of a row. Your solution could run into issues if there's only 7 items, the row never closes.

I also removed the `$count` var, not sure why that's used when it stores the same as `$i`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='row'> 
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++): ?>
            <div class="span4">
                Col <?php echo $i ?>
            </div>
             <?php if ($i %3 == 0): ?>
                 </div><div class="row">
             <?php endif ?>
         <?php endfor ?>
    </div>
</div>
```